# Is a nested query necessary here?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Lets say I have a table which stores race results. Each day, several cars race around a track and I record the positions. (This is a gross simplification but it gets the point across)

The table looks like this:

```
|Driver | Position | Date
 Andy     1          22/06/2011
 Paul     2          22/06/2011
 Cliff    3          22/06/2011
 Andy     2          21/06/2011
 Paul     1          21/06/2011
 Cliff    3          21/06/2011
```

And so on...

I would like to write a query which returns the driver positions for a given date, but also the positions for the previous day. I would like for this to return the following columns:

```
|Driver | Position | Date       | Position Yesterday
 Andy     1          22/06/2011   2
 Paul     2          22/06/2011   1
 Cliff    3          22/06/2011   3
```

I presume I would have to write a nested query, but I don't really know where to start. I know that I could call the database multiple times and build the results in my application, but I don't feel like it's best practice.

Comment: Why do you return the date? It's redundant.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it is. It doesn't have to return the date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  [today].*,
  [yesterday].Position
FROM
  yourTable AS [today]
LEFT JOIN
  yourTable AS [yesterday]
    ON  [today].Driver = [yesterday].Driver
    AND [today].Date   = [yesterday].Date + 1
WHERE
  [today].Date = '22/06/2011'
```

Comment: Just a heads up. `Date + 1` will fail if OP uses SQL Server 2008 and data type `DATE`.

Answer (score 4):

you may do left join like this:

```
select
  r1.driver,
  r1.position,
  r1.date
  r2.position as prev_pos
from
  results r1
left join
  results r2 on r1.driver = r2.driver and r2.date = r1 - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

Answer (score 2):

Nesting seems to performing better (thanks @Dems for his comments)
Self join the table by filtering the dates. Use and index on (driver, date) combination

```
SELECT t1.Driver,t1.Position, t1.Date, t2.Position
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Driver, Position FROM table ON t1.Driver = t2.Driver AND t2.date ='21/06/2001') ON t1.Driver = t2.Driver
WHERE t1.date = '22/06/2011'
```

Comment: You need to put the `AND t2.date = '21/06/2011'` in the LEFT JOIN.  If there isn't a record for yesterday, `t2.date` will be NULL and cause the WHERE clause to fail.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but is `DATEDIFF(DAY, a, b) = 1` SARGable?  And/or, how would this compare with `a = DATEADD(DAY, -1, b)`?

Comment: I change it again since subquery seems to perform better. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MS SQL Server 2008, have a look at [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UNION, one query for the first results UNION results for the second query. That should return it the right way:

SELECT * FROM * WHERE *=*

UNION

SELECT * FROM * WHERE *=*

Fill in the *s for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a join, searching for the previous day.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test SQL queries right here but here is some pseudo SQL-Code that might work if translated to proper SQL:

```
SELECT
  today.driver,
  today.position,
  today.date,
  yesterday.position
FROM
  your_table today,
  ( SELECT driver, position, ( date - 1 day ) "date" FROM your_table ) yesterday
WHERE
  today.driver = yesterday.driver AND
  today.date = yesterday.date
```

This does not compile of course, and I am not 100% sure about the where clause. You might have to do some left/right outer joins. Also, you will have a problem when the last race was not yesterday, but the day before.

Hope this helps anyway.

Comment: This is an odd way of doing it, although it can certainly work.  Except for one thing...  You need to ADD a day to yesterday for it to equal today, you're subrtracting a day from yesterday, which means that you'll join on to tomorrow's records.

Comment: I was thinking of date - 1 day in a logial way, of course it must be done the other way round in the end. I would prefer the solution you posted either way, though. Just didn't have it in the list of already posted answers when I posted mine

Answer (score 0):

Just another option:

```
@givendate = '22/06/2011'

SELECT t1.Driver
     , t1.Position
     , t1.Date
     , ( SELECT t2.Position
         FROM table t2
         WHERE t2.Driver = t1.Driver
           AND t2.date = DATEADD(day, @givendate, -1)
       ) AS PositionYesterday
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.date = @givendate
```